# Elastic search tokenizing my query string, an email address. How to stop it?

Tags: elasticsearch

My type is user: email and username.

The email field is set to type string, with a custom analyzer 'exact_lower':

```
index.analysis.analyzer.exact_lower:
  type: custom
  tokenizer: keyword
  filter : lowercase
```

The problem is when I search for a full email address it is returning matches as if the '@' was a space. I assume due to it tokenizing the search.

Query I'm sending in:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "query_string" : {
      "query" : "admin@example.com"
    }
  }
}
```

It is returning anything matching 'admin' or 'example.com'. E.g. admin@example.com, admin@abc.com, and john@example.com. I want it to only return admin@example.com...

I think I need to tell the search not to tokenize the `query_string`, but haven't been able to figure out how to do that.

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks,
Seth

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's like that because `query_string` is using the `_all` field as the default field to search on. And that field has its own analyzer.

Defining an analyzer for your `email` field is not applying the same analyzer to the `_all` field. More details about `_all` you can find [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html).

To match exactly the email address I suggest a different query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "email": {
        "value": "admin@example.com"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

or using `query_string`, but referring to a specific field:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "email:admin@example.com"
    }
  }
}
```